# How may I echo all but the last parameter in bash?

Tags: bash, parameter, bash-functions

I have the following

```
#!/bin/bash
function f1 ()
{
  echo "${@:1:-2}"
}
f1 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I need to echo `1 2 3 4 5`
`man bash` tells me that when I use `@` I can't use a negative length.

I resorted to using a calculating (`"${@:1:$((${#@}-1))}"`) which is seeming unorthodox to me.

How do I exclude the last parameter from outputting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "${@:1:$#-1}"
```

The length argument is already in an arithmetic context, so there's no need for `$(( ... ))`, and the number of arguments is given by `$#` so there's no need to try to use the equivalent of `${#...[@]}` on `$@`.