# Bash still cut the last part of the third parameter even if I attempted `$*` and `$@`

Tags: bash, shell-script, parameter

I have tried the following questions:

- [Propagate all arguments in a bash shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824590/propagate-all-arguments-in-a-bash-shell-script)
- [How may I echo all but the last parameter in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487085/how-may-i-echo-all-but-the-last-parameter-in-bash)

I was running `docker-compose` that checks Dockerfile.

See my script:

```bsh
archlinux="pacman"

get_package_manager_install()
{
  if [[ -x "$(command -v $1)" ]]; then
    "$1 $2 $3"
  else        
    echo "Gestor do pacote desconhecido" &>/dev/null;
  fi
}

get_package_manager_install "$archlinux"     "-S --noconfirm --needed" "ca-certificates curl git p7zip wget unzip zstd"
get_package_manager_install "$archlinux"     "-S --noconfirm --needed" "htop micro neofetch neovim zsh"
get_package_manager_install "$archlinux"     "-S --noconfirm --needed" "luit xdotool xdriinfo xorg-appres xorg-iceauth xorg-xcmsdb xorg-xgamma xorg-sessreg xorg-xdpyinfo xorg-xev xorg-xfd xorg-xfontsel xorg-xhost xorg-xkbcomp xorg-xkill xorg-xlsatoms xorg-xlsclients xorg-xlsfonts xorg-xmessage xorg-xmodmap xorg-xprop xorg-xrandr xorg-xrdb xorg-xrefresh xorg-xset xorg-xvidtune xorg-xvinfo xorg-xwininfo"
```

Observe that I also already have replaced `"$1 $2 $3"` with `$@` or `$*`. I also attempted `$(echo "$@")` and `$(echo "${@}")`

I also have already replaced `" "` with `' '` in the last parameter, but unsuccessfully.

It cut the last part of the parameter, for example, `git p7zip wget unzip zstd` and whole `htop micro neofetch neovim zsh` will not be installed.

Comment: I see no `$*` or ~$@` in your script.

Comment: I can't tell what you mean Bash "cutting the last part of the third parameter". If you want to know why some particular result happens, it would help if you show it. Maybe with the package manager replaced with e.g. `printf "<%s>\n" ...` which would print the args in a somewhat unambiguous format. (Also note that `$*`, `$@`, `"$*"` and `"$@"` are different.)

Comment: But in general, you probably shouldn't try to shove multiple strings/arguments into one string/argument, it's just bound to give you problems. See [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373) for similar issues and some explanation. The solution of using an array isn't really needed here but you'll get similar issues with unquoted variable expansions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `-S`, `--noconfirm`, `--needed` and the packages to be passed as separate arguments to `pacman`, so:

```
archlinux="pacman"

get_package_manager_install()
{
  if command -v -- "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    "$@"
  else        
    echo >&2 "Gestor do pacote desconhecido"
    return 1
  fi
}

get_package_manager_install "$archlinux" -S --noconfirm --needed ca-certificates curl git p7zip wget unzip zstd
```

Where `get_package_manager_install` is passed all those as separate arguments, and `get_package_manager_install` passes them as-is to `pacman`.

If you wanted `get_package_manager_install` to take only 3 arguments,  and the second and third to be split on space characters to generate the list of arguments to pass to `pacman`, you could use the split+glob operator (which you used already by mistake by forgetting to quote `$1` in your code), after having disabled the glob part and set `$IFS` to space:

```
get_package_manager_install() {
  if command -v -- "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    (
      set -o noglob
      IFS=' '
      exec "$1" $2 $2
    )
  else        
    echo >&2 "Gestor do pacote desconhecido"
    return 1
  fi
}

get_package_manager_install "$archlinux" \
                            '-S --noconfirm --needed'
                            'ca-certificates curl git p7zip wget unzip zstd'
```

Though I can't imagine why you'd want to do that.

It's also not clear to me why you'd name the variable holding the name of the package manager `archlinux` which is the name of a Linux distribution.

Comment: If `get_package_manager_install "$mageia" "" "ca-certificates curl git p7zip wget unzip zstd"`, would it be `get_package_manager_install "$mageia" ca-certificates curl git p7zip wget unzip zstd`? Observe that the second parameter is empty because `uprmi` does not have any option for installing.

Comment: As for the `archlinux` variable, check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/690666/bash-function-condition-comand-argument-misinterprets-strangely-and-wrongly-ubun. I used to use the original commands, but the Bash functions do not recognise the original command.

Comment: To better understand, you can check my file (observe that it is a bit old): https://github.com/gusbemacbe/complete-linux/blob/main/scripts/1-root

Comment: @stéphane-chanzelas, I tested both your examples, but I checked `which zsh`, it informed `zsh` does not exist. My script seems to have more problems. Sorry! :-/

Comment: Ah, please forgive me for my stupidity, I investigated and figured out why `git`, `htop`, `micro`, `neofetch`, `zsh`, etc., weren't installed, then it turned that there were files that already existed in the filesystem before. I had to remove them from my project, and they were installed. Only your first example worked. The next time, I have to inspect the log I export with `tee` to check the errors.